# Dynamic LINQ API - SQL Convert Function

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, dynamic-linq

I'm trying to use a Dynamic LINQ Query to query a SQL database, and in the Where clause I need to evaluate an '=' condition with a field that is of type TEXT.

Right now, I've got this:

```
var result = DBCon.PcInValue
   .Where(String.Format("InputName = @0 and InputValue) {0} @1", f.Condition), f.Field, f.Value)
   .Select("new(OrderNum, OrderLine)");
```

This doesn't work since you can't use the equal operator on a TEXT data type.
The field that is type TEXT is "InputValue". I tried to convert it like so:

```
var result = DBCon.PcInValue
   .Where(String.Format("InputName = @0 and Convert(nvarchar(100), InputValue) {0} @1", f.Condition), f.Field, f.Value)
   .Select("new(OrderNum, OrderLine)");
```

But it looks like this is not supported.

Anyone have any clues as to how I can do this?

EDIT:
The following SQL Syntax works with no issues, but again I'm not sure if this is possible using the Dynamic LINQ API:

```
SELECT [t0].[OrderNum], [t0].[OrderLine]
FROM [PcInValue] AS [t0]
WHERE ([t0].[InputName] = 'OpenWidthFt')  AND (Convert(nvarchar(100), [t0].[InputValue]) = '10')
```

Answer (score 1):

I've tested this and it seems to work fine (though it's a bit odd):

```
var result = DBCon.PcInValue
   .Where(String.Format("InputName = @0 and InputValue.ToString() {0} @1", f.Condition), f.Field, f.Value)
   .Select("new(OrderNum, OrderLine)");
```

LinqPad tells me it's translated into something similar to the following (using my own table):

```
SELECT [t0].[Id], [t0].[Name], [t0].[InputValue]
FROM [People] AS [t0]
WHERE (CONVERT(NVarChar(MAX),[t0].[InputValue])) = @p0
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. The resulting query is the same as before:

SELECT [t0].[OrderNum], [t0].[OrderLine]
FROM [PcInValue] AS [t0]
WHERE ([t0].[InputName] = 'OpenWidthFt') AND ([t0].[InputValue] = '10')

Comment: Odd. Just to make sure, when you leave out the `.ToString()`, what error message do you receive? I get "SQL Server does not handle comparison of NText, Text, Xml, or Image data types." This is when hitting a SQL Server 2005 (Express) instance.

Comment: I get a similar error message saying that NVarChar to Text is not comparable with the equals operator.

Comment: I'm guessing this is the exact error you're getting: "The data types text and nvarchar are incompatible in the equal to operator." I can reproduce that when InputValue's Server Data Type (property in dbml) is set to `NVarChar(255) NOT NULL` instead of `Text`, as it should be. Could you check and confirm that it's still set to Text?

Comment: I just checked: The InputValue field is of type Text and nullable. This is on SQL Server 2005.

Comment: A few more quick thoughts - Does this work without using dynamic linq (keeping the .ToString())? Both ways seemed to work fine for me (generating that same `CONVERT` sql above). Are you using .NET 3.5 SP1? I am, but I wouldn't think that would matter, unless this was an SP1 fix. I'm running out of ideas :(

Comment: Also, the default response seems to be "convert to use nvarchar instead of text", but I'm assuming that isn't an option for you.

Comment: Maybe we're using different Dynamic Linq libraries? Can you link me to whichever one you're using? I got mine from the link over at Scott Gu's blog: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/bb894665.aspx (C-Sharp Samples).

Comment: Yeah converting the datatype is not an option, unfortunately. :\

Comment: That should be the same one I have. Did you try a query without using dynamic linq? That suggestion was to help remove the dynamic linq factor from the problem.

Comment: I'll have to give that a whirl tonight when I get home. Thanks so much for your help thus far Ryan.